# Rails many to one association - Help showing many in one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

These are my models:

```
class Bedommelse < ActiveRecord::Base belongs_to :virksomhed_primary,
:class_name => 'Virksomhed',
:foreign_key => 'virksomhed_id' belongs_to :virksomheds, 
:foreign_key => "virksomhed_id" 
end

class Bedommelse < ActiveRecord::Base belongs_to :virksomheds, 
:foreign_key => "virksomhed_id" belongs_to :freelances, 
:foreign_key => "freelance_id" 
end
```

I am trying to display the name of the `virksomhed_id` not the `id` itself in the **One View** (Bedommelse view)

I can show the column `virksomhed_id`:

```
   <% @bedommelses.each do |bedommelse| %>
     <p><%= bedommelse.virksomhed_id</p>
   <% end %>
```

How do I show the name of the virksomhed?

I have tried this but it didn't work.

```
   <% @bedommelses.each do |bedommelse| %>
     <p><%= bedommelse.virksomhed.navn </p>
   <% end %>
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: Yes, it would be helpful to have properly formatted classes. However, it looks like the two classes you've added have the same name. I assume one of them is meant to be Verksomhed.

Answer (score 1):

I have found my mistake
I did a fail in the models:
It should be:

```
belongs_to :virksomhed
```

not

```
belongs_to :virksomheds
```

And the view should be:

```
<%= @bedommelse.virksomhed.navn %>
```